# Unnecessary Ada dependency recompilations (GCC 5.3.0)

Tags: gcc, ada, gnat

After a recent GCC update, we noticed some of our precompiled common functions were being recompiled every time an application using them was built. It appears to be related to our use of gnat.adc files to store pragmas. I do have a workaround, but it isn't pretty and I was hoping someone could tell me whether I'm doing something wrong.

Directory structure:

```
~/adatest
    -dependency
        dependency.ads
        dependency.adb
        gnat.adc
    -dependent
        dependent.adb
        gnat.adc
```

Files:

```
--dependency.ads
package dependency is
   procedure donothing;
end dependency;


--dependency.adb
with ada.text_io;
package body dependency is
   procedure donothing is
begin
   ada.text_io.put_line("Doing nothing");
end;
end dependency;

--dependent.adb
with dependency;
procedure dependent is
begin
   dependency.donothing;
end dependent;
```

gnat.adc files are both empty.

Compiling:

```
cd ~/adatest/dependency
/usr/gnat/bin/gnatmake -m dependency.adb
ls
    dependency.adb  dependency.ads  dependency.ali  dependency.o  gnat.adc
cd ../dependent/
/usr/gnat/bin/gnatmake -m dependent.adb -I../dependency
ls
    dependency.ali  dependency.o  dependent  dependent.adb  dependent.ali  dependent.o  gnat.adc
```

So compiling dependent recompiled dependency, even though dependency was already compiled. Using gnatmake's verbose flag, I can see why:

```
gcc -c -I../dependency dependent.adb
  "~/adatest/dependency/dependency.ali" being checked ...
    -> "gnat.adc" time stamp mismatch
```

It appears that the gnat.adc timestamp stored in dependency.ali (which is the timestamp of the dependency directory's gnat.adc) is being compared against the timestamp of the dependent directory's gnat.adc, causing the mismatch and recompilation. Removing either gnat.adc file stops the recompilation, but we need those pragmas in our actual program. It looks like our previous GCC version (4.8.2) didn't store gnat.adc timestamps, so this problem never occurred.

Anyway, our current workaround is renaming all the gnat.adc files to gnat.adc.tmp, and then specifying the file with gnatmake's configuration file parameter (-gnatec=gnat.adc.tmp). The .tmp extension stops the files from being indexed in the .ali, solving the problem. I don't really like this kludge, though, and was hoping there was a cleaner solution.

Comment: You’d have to be careful about which pragmas were partition-wide and which not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a matter of specifying library directories. In directory `dependent`, and after compiling in directory `dependency`,

```
$ gnatmake -m -A../dependency dependent.adb
```

I.e., use `-Adir` (as described in the output of `gnatmake` when run without anything). Then,

```
$ ls
dependent   dependent.adb   dependent.ali   dependent.o gnat.adc
```